# Vaadin 7: Is there a way for Vaadin to notice if a label overflows?

Tags: java, css, label, overflow, vaadin7

**Is there a way in Vaadin server-side code to know, if contents of a label overflow?**

I have an area in the UI for containing descriptions of different kind of services. Sometimes the descriptions are so long, that they're not shown completely. Currently it is made so, that the content of the label is shown completely when the user hovers mouse over it, with following css:

```
.p-service-description {
    padding: 0.5em;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    max-height: 7.8em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.p-service-description:hover {
    display: block;
    max-height: inherit;
    -webkit-line-clamp: none;
}
```

The server-side code for the label is currently as follows:

```
    Label descriptionLabel = labelBuilder()
            .with(currentService.getDescription()
            .replaceAll("\\r?\\n", "<br>"))
            .asHTML().withStyle("p-service-description")
            .getObject();
```

That works as intended, however, now it is required that there would be an "expand button" showing whenever the content overflows and only by clicking that button would all the content be shown.

I was wondering if there is a mechanism in Vaadin server-side code to somehow notice if the content overflows and then show a button for expanding the content to be shown completely, as it currently does only when mouse is being hovered over the content.

So is there a way to do this in Vaadin server-side code or do I need to start hacking with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The Label should show all content on client side.
Try to use below:

```
label.setImmediate(true);
label.setSizeUndefined();
```

You have also option of putting this label in a Panel (that will auto scroll in the client side).

You can also option of having a logic in server side depends on string's length that the label should show. if the length is greater than a predefined LENGTH you only set a part of it to the label and show an expand button beside it, else you show only the label with the whole string.